# Best way to add voting to list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of items and I want to add ability to vote up or down. I am not sure how to architect this.

1. Should I make the votes a table and put more info about the votes like the people who voted?
2. Regardless of #1, once a person votes, I can make an ajax and jquery call to update the database with the vote count, but how do I update the page on which the vote was made without refreshing the page? If the vote was in item n which isn't first or last, I can't use append or prepend functions in jQuery, so how can I update that exact item?

Comment: "Need input." - Johnny5
What have you tried?

Comment: @Mully I am still in the planning phases of this feature. Just not sure how to have the person press the upvote button and have that display right away on the page.

Comment: How mutch data will be displayed on one item? If not much, you can make your ajax call return the html and update the div that have those items with the new order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you got downvoted for this - seems like a good question to me...

Anyway, I'd recommend storing who voted along with the total number of votes - it'll let you prevent people from voting as many times as they want, which you couldn't do with just vote totals.

And assuming the link that gets clicked to cast a vote is within the LI it applies to, you can use [jQuery's `success` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and the fact that `$(this)` will refer to the link that got clicked, to find the LI you want:

```
$('a.vote').click(function() {
    //Save the value of $(this) - 
    //I'm not positive it'll be the same in the callback:
    var clicked_link = $(this);
    jQuery.ajax({
        // some options
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            var li = clicked_link.closest('li.votable');
            //update the vote count from `data`
        },
        //some other options
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - yeah seems like a good question to me too lol.  I see what you are doing in your jQuery example. It makes good sense.